# Zapier cli : how can I retrieve my pushed source code?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I've been converting my zapier app with zapier-cli and I've used the push command to send some beautiful precious features in my app.

Unfortunately - and I blame myself for it -, I didn't push it on github or either not in any versioning tool. And of course I can't access my code anymore -_- So my question is, is there any way to retrieve or pull my source code from the web app?

I've checked the documentations and I couldn't find any pull-likely command
ANd On the web app, there is no way to see the code from the developper platform.

Does someone know if there is a way ? Any advice (except for versioning advice) would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Bad news and good news. First off, there's no direct way for you to pull it down.

The good news part of that is that we do keep a copy of a lot of pieces of it (so we can run it!) so if you write into `partners@zapier.com` and reference this question, we should be able to sort you out.

Note that this *should not* be considered a primary backup method and it's important to always have access to your code. Do be careful in the future. :)

Comment: Thank you David ! Good to know :)
I've manage to get my work back and I pushed it on my github repo so I'm all right now.